# Диалог ввода текста

Tags: customview, android

Хочу сделать диалог с EditText и кнопкой, по нажатии кнопки забрать текст из et, вот так примерно

[image: снимок]

пробовал с помощью AlertDialog, не нашел, как вставить EditText. Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну а что [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) разве не подходит? Припишите к `Dialog` свой лэйаут типа:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        >
<TableRow>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:text="Искать"
        android:layout_width="0dp"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

и вперед!

Answer (score 2):

Может поздно, зато кому-то может пригодиться))

http://androprog.blogspot.ru/2013/03/android_10.html